# Recursively traverse a directory?

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, cifs

On Linux, how would I recursively traverse a variable number of shares?

Comment: What language.  is "find . -type d" is a good start for shell scripting.

Comment: Are shares mounted? If not you can use smbclient.

Comment: You need to add more detail to the question so it actually means something :). We can guess what you mean and give you nik's answer but we don't actually know what you want yet.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered your other question.
The generic directory traversal from a point above the shares would be,

```
find . -type d -exec ls -ld {} \;
```

This will enumerate all the directories under your base directory.

You could however, run this individually over a list of the shared directories to get separated results.